# How to filter data from mapped data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am displaying cards with data mapped with a price and location

```
  return data.map( FD1 => (

       <Row>
         <Card className="card">
            <Card body className="text-center">

               <CardTitle data-es-label="location"> Location:
                       {FD1.Departure}
               </CardTitle>


                <CardText data-es-label="Price">Price
                        {FD1.price} 
                   </CardText>


              <label>
                  <Checkbox
                      id={FD1.FlightID}
                    name={FD1.FlightID}
                  checked={this.state.checked === FD1.FlightID}
                 onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}/>
                      <span>Select</span>
               </label>

      <CardActions>'
```

Each card has a check box and my idea was when the check box is selected and submitted - the information mapped to that card will be sent to be 'booked'.

Is it possible to filter data from the mapped data. Each 'card' with the data has a unique id. How do I filter the data by card and send to a booking page with the details?

At the moment when I select a checked box they all select.

```
 handleCheckboxChange = event =>
        this.setState({ checked: event.target.checked });
```

EDIT: attempt - this is what I have tried

```
  handleCheckboxChange = event =>
        this.setState({ checked: event.target.checked });

   Select(FD) {

 this.state={checked:FD.FlightID};

       return(
            <label>
                <Checkbox id={FD.FlightID}
                          name={FD.FlightID}
                          checked={this.state.checked}
                          onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
                />
                <span>Select</span>
            </label>



        )
    }
```

Do you know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Currently, the issue is that there is only a single `checked` state for all items. Instead try moving the mapped item into it's own component and moving the `checked` state into it

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give that a go

Answer (score 1):

into the checked state save the FD1.FlightID instead of true/false and you will know exactly which card had been checked.

and then on submit you can send the appropriate data using this.state.checked (the id of checked card)

Comment: If you only need to select 1 card and send that card's data. Then I would do this.

Comment: even if he needs multiple values he can save ids as array and use that array later

Comment: Yes, @Dito. But just clarifying what they are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In the code inside your "map" function, "this" is still referring to the parent component. So you only have one checked state. That's why all your checkboxes show the same behaviour.

A cleaner solution would be to define a new stateful component "CardRow" that has everything inside the map plus it's own state and handleCheckboxChange function.